# jDigiClock in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, jquery

I'm trying to implement the [jDigiClock jQuery plugin](http://www.radoslavdimov.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-digiclock/) for showing the time and the weather in a really cool way in SharePoint 2010. It uses either PHP or ASPX to fetch weather info. I placed all the files into the SiteAssets but SharePoint will only let me download the main index.html page, not to run it from that location; this was just to see if it would work.

Anyone know how this could be implemented in SharePoint? If not, it's not a biggie; just a nice feature to have, not a must have. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view index.html by using dav. Push "Open with Explorer" button on the ribbon, "Connect&Export" group, "Library" tab.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a Content Editor web part.  Once you click the webpart you will see an "Edit Html Source" option in the ribbon.  Do that, and just plop in your code.  Since you already have your js files in Site Assets you should be all set.